# Implementation of an enterprise license

Tags: c#, licensing

I've developed a piece of software n C#.

And I already implemented a way for customers to upgrade the software using a single license key.

The single license keys are (32 chars) calculated based on some hardware stuff which isn't likely to change (a lot).

This all works pretty good.

However now I want to implement a enterprise license.

Basically I want the customer to be able to license the software on different (unlimited) machines with only one key (so I cannot use the hardware checks for this).

What would be an approach for this?

There are some things I can think of:

- Hardcode 1 license key in the software which always works
- Build custom programs for enterprises on request with their hardcoded license key in it (not really something I would like to do)
- Make some function / algo / something that will check if a entered license key is valid (and still be able to use different keys per enterprise also 32 chars long).

The last option will be preferred I think.

However I cannot come up with a way to check if the entered license is a valid enterprise license.

PS

I am not looking for a way to completely stop piracy of my application, just a simple way to implement an enterprise license.

Comment: Why not expose the validation and product registration via a Web Service, and or Website, and authenticate against that?

Comment: @Lloyd: My customers already have to request the license via web. And the application may run on a machine without an active internet connection. I would hate to see to let my paying customers have to make another request on another machine to validate the purchased license. Once they purchased the software I really don't want to bother them anymore :)

Comment: Then you'll have to use some form of hard coded Private key to validate the code. I have seen it done using the version number of the EXE and a coded private key so that upgrades can use the same key.

Comment: If there's not an active internet connection, would it be available sometimes? Would there still be lan connectivity? I recommend automatic messages to either a central server in lan or yours on the internet. Track usage and enforce later if required. Change from technical problem to administrative problem. If they breach the contract, scare them with an email that you know. If they persist send an invoice, if they don't pay send a legal cease and desist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, you should go for the solution that results in the least amount of friction for your paying customers.

People will either pay for your software or not, and as long as you have some kind of mechanism to validate licenses, it really doesn't matter how strong it is. There is not a single piece of software that I can think of for which you can't find working pirated copies, which to a large extent makes all efforts in this direction wasted.

One of the things that bother me the most is when the pirated copy is better than the paid-for version. As an example, the virtual CD/DVD software Daemon Tools is protected by a mechanism that sounds somewhat similar to yours. It generates a machine and software-version specific key and is generally a hassle to use legally. I own a 5-PC license and if I want to update it, I have to go and revoke the old-version licenses, issue a new one and re-register the updated software. Repeat for every installation. I've often considered just using a cracked version as it provides a much simpler upgrade path, which basically just involves installing the software.

I realize that you have probably considered all this and may be of a different opinion, but your guiding principle should be to make the paid-for experience beat the pirated one.

Comment: Please spread your word to the PC gaming industry!

Comment: @Ucodia Good example too! Sadly, they seem to be pedagogically out of reach..

Comment: I'm aware of all you above concerns. Hence the last line in the question as well as my comment on LLoyd's comment. However I'm still looking for some way to be able to use some (pseudo-)random entreprise key. You say: `It generates a machine and software-version specific key and is generally a hassle to use legally` --> that's just for the single license key I'm now just looking for a way to enter an enterprise key which doesn't use some hash of the hardware e.g.

Comment: Unless you want to go down the path of using the domain or workgroup name, it's probably hard to find something that is somewhat unique to base it on. Can you perhaps explain what you think the difference between an enterprise and a normal key is, apart from the latter being machine-locked? Why have the machine-lock anyway? (I get new hardware at least every two years and probably reinstall Windows from scratch twice for every PC, which would make your current solution a hassle, imho).

Comment: `Can you perhaps explain what you think the difference between an enterprise and a normal key is, apart from the latter being machine-locked?` That's the exact difference. `Why have the machine-lock anyway?` To find out the installations of the program. `I get new hardware at least every two years` So you need to request (free) a new license every 2 years big deal... `(I get new hardware at least every two years and probably reinstall Windows from scratch twice for every PC, which would make your current solution a hassle, imho)` if you would have multiple pc you would have a enterprise

Comment: license. So no extra hassle there. Also you would have to enter your license on every piece of software. So again my question is not about the effect / or whatever of using a hardware based serial I asked a question on how to implement (pseudo-)random enterprise key

Comment: You say "big deal", but for me who has to request 20 new licenses (to different software) makes it a real pain. I was advocating the fact that regardless how fancy or secure your protection is it will be broken, so the best solution is something that is entirely hassle-free. That way you just have to generate keys, no machine-key or pseudo-randomness needed. Have the software report back to a central server during installation or on first run if you want to track installations.